# Suitable permissions for owncloud /data directory using nginx under centos

Tags: permissions, nginx, selinux

Having the following software:

- nginx web server
- centos 7.1 OS
- owncloud 8 Application
- https Web Browsing Protocol
- PHP-FPM

  ---

After resolving the issue of `/config` directory permissions, we reached this error:

> Can't create or write into the data directory
>   /usr/share/nginx/owncloud/data

I tried all of the following commands:

```
 chown -R nginx:nginx data
 chmod -R 750 data
# 2nd attempt
 chown -R apache:apache data
 chmod -R 750 data
# 3rd attempt
 chown -R nginx:nginx data
 chmod -R 777 data
# 4th attempt
 chown -R apache:apache data
 chmod -R 777 data
```

Nothing works -- same error message.

- Does this require `setsebool` intervention (SELinux)?
- Does permission modification require a restart of one of the services?
- It is not a suitable owner -- `nginx` or `apache` -- knowing that `http` and `www-data` do not exist?

Comment: is your php_fpm running under webserver identity ?

Comment: yes . i have php_fpm

Answer (score 0):

Delete `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default`  , since i have already `/etc/nginx/conf.d/owncloud.conf`

This step resolves my issue .